# What is the purpose of this wire in these string lights?

Tags: lighting

These lights are from a pre-lit tree. Segments of the string have an additional wire that truncates with these different sockets. I thought that these sockets provided a splice to make a connection but there is no metal in those odd plastic side pieces that form a connection. What is the purpose of pushing this wire in to the side of these sockets?

[image]

[image]

Comment: do the lights "twinkle" or flash? If so, is the strand capable of having some on while some are off? If so, then that 3rd wire is used to switch different subsets on and off. In the case of fairy lights, a 3rd wire can also be used to supply power to both ends of the strand to prevent one end looking dimmer than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christmas light sets use multiple sets of bulbs wired in series.  Because of the way they are sectioned out, sometimes they need 3 wires to run the length, and sometimes just two wires.  Occasionally one of the wires may not be used, but is still a part of the winding process when they make up the sets.  This wire needs to be terminated, so a little plastic tab to hold it works fine.

Comment: I wondered if this was just part of the manufacturing process, our byproduct.

Comment: Yea, that's what I believe.  A wire that's not electrically connected doesn't serve an electrical purpose, but it could be left in place to give the strand strength or just because leaving it is easier for the equipment that makes the strands.

Comment: Any set that provides a socket on the other end needs 3 wires.  Always-hot+neutral must run full length, and there is a 3rd wire between the lights on each string within the set.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely just a plastic wire(without any metal conductors) used to help bind the lights together as a strand or secure to a tree/bush. Helps to prevent tugging on the wires when moving or mounting. In your instance they appear to be present just to keep the lights on the tree branches.

Have dissasembled plenty of light sets and prelit trees with these extra "wires".  They can be removed if needed.